# Take top count dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which takes integer values as a `@top` from me so that I can use it in my query, but it's not allowing me to set value of top dynamically.

```
select top @top * from (select url,
count(1) as shared from tblshared
group by url, uniqid having
uniqid = @uniqid) as sha  order by
shared desc
```

I want to retrieve top `n` records from table so I want to pass the value of `n` in stored procedure and it will return me that number of top records.

Note: I don't want to use `exec`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SET ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx):

```
SET ROWCOUNT @top
SELECT ...
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: -1 This applies to intermediate results. So aggregates and sub queries can be *wrong*. TOP applies as expected

Answer (score 4):

That will work fine if you wrap @top in brackets

```
select top (@top) * 
from ( 
    select url, count(1) as shared 
    from tblshared 
    group by url, uniqid 
    having uniqid=@uniqid) as sha 
order by shared desc
```

Comment: getting this error: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('. its showing error on '('

Comment: Try removing the top clause entirely and see if it will run without it, failing that what version of sqlserver are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` isntead of top

```
with t1 as(
    select url,row_number() over(
                partition by url, uniqid order by url, uniqid desc) as shared 
    from tblshared
    where uniqid = @uniqid )

select * from t1 where shared < @top
```

[REF](http://google.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @v1 int
set @v1 = 25
set rowcount @v1
select * from MyTable Order by DateColumn
set rowcount 0
```

Comment: -1 This applies to intermediate results. So aggregates and sub queries can be wrong. TOP applies as expected